# Does this question belong on Stack Overflow, Ask Ubuntu or Server Fault?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

This thread [Logging MySQL query on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614429/logging-mysql-query-on-ubuntu) is little bit confusing me. Does it really belong to Stack Overflow? There are three sites it could belong to

- Stack Overflow
- Ask Ubuntu
- Server Fault

But I would prefer Ubuntu or Server Fault more. What's your opinion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a question about the configuration of a server/service and belongs on ServerFault.

- It does not belong on SO because it isn't a programming question and only vaguely related with programming.
- It does not belong on AU because it is not a specific question about Ubuntu.

**Update:** For example a [very similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/223434/turn-log-slow-queries-on) has already been asked/answered on ServerFault.

Comment: okay, I think you specified it all. Thanks

Comment: I think another option could be [DBA.SE].

Comment: The question would be technically on-topic on [ubuntu.se]; it doesn't matter it's not specifically about Ubuntu, as long it is about Ubuntu and an Ubuntu-specific answer is acceptable. [unix.se] is another possibility. But neither AU nor U&L have much MySQL expertise, there's more on [sf].

Comment: There's further MySQL expertise on [dba.se] and we would've taken it as well. However, in this case I think one of the unixy sites would've been good. It seems to have been a configuration error. Alas, hindsight.

Answer (score 1):

From the not-really-one-and-never-read [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq):

> Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers …
>
> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm
> - ***software tools commonly used by programmers***
> - matters that are unique to the programming profession

Please note, ***software tools commonly used by programmers*** *does* include RDBMSes.  I would also argue that this includes how to configure and manage them, as long as this is from a programmer's perspective.

As the user is asking how to track queries run on the database, and this is an action quite often done by programmers, I think the question is well within the hazy penumbra of on-topic questions on StackOverflow.

***Edit:***  I always forget about [DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/).  I'd migrate there before migrating to SF/SU.